# Can I clean /var/lib/docker/tmp?

Tags: docker, coreos

My server is CoreOS. There are so many files in `/var/lib/docker/tmp`, their name's like "`GetV2ImageBlob998303926`".

The size of all `GetV2ImageBlobxxxxxxxx` files is 640MB.

Can I remove all files in `/var/lib/docker/tmp`?

Comment: This question is not programming related and would be a better fit for superuser

Comment: You can delete the dir `/var/lib/docker/tmp` directly, and restart your containers. Hope it save your time.

Answer (score 8):

This is reported in [issues/14506](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14506), and addressed in <del>[PR 14389](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/14389)</del>, now [PR 15414](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15414).

> ### Ensure images downloaded by pullTagV2 are always cleaned up
>
> Previously, if only some of the downloads succeed, we would not close and delete the file handles. This does change the behavior of the registration to block on all downloads completing (whereas previously it would exit early after the first failure), which is necessary to ensure cleanup is only performed after the download portion has completed.

That will be fixed in Docker 1.8 or 1.9