# Upgrading Docker on DC/OS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, mesosphere, marathon, dcos

I'm running container services using Marathon on a DC/OS cluster running on AWS. After ~3 weeks some of the slave nodes ran out of free space. I've checked inside the nodes and saw that the folder /var/lib/docker/tmp was filled up with ~24gb of data that was not automatically elimintaed by the Docker agent.

According to [Can I clean /var/lib/docker/tmp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489802/can-i-clean-var-lib-docker-tmp) the issue was fixed in Docker 1.8, but my nodes all have Docker 1.7 installed on them.

My question is - is there any way to automatically upgrade Docker on all nodes at once, or should I ssh into each and every one of them to do the upgrade?

Comment: I have the same issue with docker 17.04 under DC/OS