# Free up space after removing all images & containers

Tags: docker, diskspace

I have deleted all the images/containers

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/var/lib/docker$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu@ubuntu:/var/lib/docker$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

I notice that there is still about 15GB used inside `/var/lib/docker`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/var/lib/docker$ sudo du --max-depth=1 -h .
12G     ./volumes
104K    ./aufs
4,0K    ./containers
1,3M    ./image
4,0K    ./trust
4,0K    ./swarm
2,6G    ./tmp
108K    ./network
15G     .
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I free up this space?
2. Is it safe to remove things inside `/var/lib/docker`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try (from docker 1.13):

```
docker system df
```

it shows you size of:

- Images
- Containers
- Local Volumes

and remove local volumes using:

```
docker volume prune
```

For older Dockers try:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check them as soon as I update my docker version

Comment: Yeah, docker version here is important. But I see you've found resolution for your issue.

Comment: It would be great to update the answer and mention the minimum Docker versions required to run each of these commands. I have Docker 1.12.1 and none of them work (`system` does not exist, `volume` doesn't have the `prune` subcommand`).

Comment: Any clue about the `/var/lib/docker/tmp` folder? I found this: [Can I clean /var/lib/docker/tmp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489802/can-i-clean-var-lib-docker-tmp) but it is not very clear to me if I can delete it.

Answer (score 5):

For my current docker version (1.12.1 for both Client & Server) a way to delete all volumes is by using:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

**but the following is safer:** (thanks Matt for your comment)

```
$(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

---

**Also from version: [1.13.0 (2017-01-18)](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1130-2017-01-18)** some commands were added:

```
$ docker system prune
$ docker container prune
$ docker image prune
$ docker volume prune
$ docker network prune
```

> *Changelog: Add new `docker system` command with `df` and `prune` subcommands for system resource management, as well as `docker {container,image,volume,network} prune` subcommands #26108 #27525 / #27525*

Comment: Using `$(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)` is a bit safer in case there are containers still around. In your case it still works the same

Answer (score 1):

Most of the space is occupied by `docker volume` as you can see from your output:

> 12G     ./volumes

Docker volumes are used to persist data for docker container and to share data between containers, and they are independent of the container’s lifecycle. So removing image/container will not free the disk space they occupied. Please refer to [their official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) for more details.

If you're using latest version of docker, you can find [volume related commands docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) for more details(list/remove/create volumes e.g), for older version of docker, you can refer to [this script on github](https://github.com/chadoe/docker-cleanup-volumes) for how to clean up volumes.

Hope this could be helpful:-)