# Docker for Windows cleanup

Tags: docker

I'm using docker for Windows to launch a MSSQL server. Everything is working fine except for the fact that my harddrive is now full. I've used all the cleanup commands that docker has, removing all images and containers:

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

This will not remove any contents in the c:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter folder, where there are still a lot of file. Roughly 130gb worth's of storage, without any running containers or stored images.

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

I tried to use the docker-ci-zap (https://github.com/jhowardmsft/docker-ci-zap) , but running that tool is not recommended so I would rather use an alternative solution

Comment: Have you tried using the -f flag (forced) and also removing the volumes with `docker volume rm [OPTIONS] VOLUME [VOLUME...]`

Comment: Jup also tried that, it keeps the windowsfilter folder, which seems to be the biggest.

Comment: Can you please try `docker system prune` and tell us? See: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/43068138/1561148](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43068138/1561148)

Comment: I tried that as well, it didnt work. I can remove the whole C:\programdata\docker folder with that docker-ci-zap tool, but it doesnt seem to be the right answere, since the creators dont recommend it(?).

Comment: hey @imacbest have you found a solution for that?

Comment: @felixsigl Nope haven't found a solution, for know I just use the docker-ci-zap whenever I run out of diskspace. This setup is not ideal since I need to remove everything and sometimes the setup breaks. I hope the windows docker team will add a good cleanup feature in the future...

Answer (score 35):

Since Docker 1.13 (January 2017), Docker has some new canonical [pruning subcommands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/pruning/) (use with care):

- [docker image prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/)
- [docker container prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/)
- [docker volume prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/)
- [docker network prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_prune/)
- [docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all dangling images
  - all build cache

However, Docker Desktop has had some sketchy upgrades that left things behind, which required manual file removal or "factory resets" for some folks.

- **Manual Deletion**

  - Mac - https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371 (This one got me a week or so ago. I resorted to pruning and [deleting data](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371#issuecomment-248404423) with `rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/*`)
  - Win - https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/745#issuecomment-319930974
- **Factory Reset** In the Docker Preferences GUI, there is a "reset to factory defaults" option. (In Docker Desktop for Mac v3.3, the option is in the "troubleshoot" tab, the icon for which looks like a bug. [image])

Comment: make sure RESTART the docker for windows, after running these prune commands or you won't see any significant change in MobyLinuxVM size

Comment: On Windows, the following script helps determine which `windowsfilter` subfolders are unused and can be deleted: https://gist.github.com/olljanat/340b4033eb24d8d33ec75f2c3c3b6b3d

Comment: **Note** make sure you try in _Windows containers_ mode as well as _Linux containers_ mode (right-click on Docker tray icon > _'Switch to Windows containers...'_), otherwise `docker system prune` and friends will not be able to clean up files related to Windows containers (`ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter`)

Comment: @sparrowt thanks, this is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

From a powershell window:

```
docker system prune -a -f
net stop com.docker.service
taskkill /F /IM "Docker Desktop.exe"
stop-vm DockerDesktopVM
Optimize-VHD -Path "C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\vm-data\DockerDesktop.vhdx" -Mode Full
start-vm DockerDesktopVM
start "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe"
net start com.docker.service
```

Comment: I ran out of space while importing images, and `docker system prune -a -f` was the only one that cleared the `windowsfilter` folder for me.

Comment: As commented above by sparrowt:

Note make sure you try in Windows containers mode as well as Linux containers mode (right-click on Docker tray icon > 'Switch to Windows containers...'), otherwise docker system prune and friends will not be able to clean up files related to Windows containers (ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter)

Answer (score 12):

Had about ~40GB for ext4.vhdx file and ~17gb for ProgramData/Docker Desktop. If you are using Docker Desktop it easy to clean it :

Just open it, click **Troubleshoot** and then **Clean/Purge data**

[image]

Works fine for me.

Comment: +1: this actually works! Unlike `docker sytem prune`, which did nothing to the Windows container data piled up in `C:/ProgramData/Docker/windowsfilter` (and, yes, "Switch to Windows Containers" was already applied anyway). Horrible form for `docker system prune` just fail silently like that...

Answer (score 7):

Just use `prune` command for `docker system` and it will **clean up every thing** just like this

```
$ docker system prune

WARNING! This will remove:
        - all stopped containers
        - all networks not used by at least one container
        - all dangling images
        - all build cache Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
```

In Docker 17.06.1 and higher, you can add the `--volumes` flag for `docker system prune` to prune volumes not used by at least one container.

For more details https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-everything

Comment: `windowsfilter` directory still balloons and doesn't get cleaned up with pruning images or system

Comment: @starscream_disco_party like @sparrowt commented in the above answer: Make sure to switch to Windows containers before running `docker system prune`.

Comment: You can do that switch from the command line with `docker context use desktop-windows`

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue after running windows containers. My `windowsfilter` folder size increased to ~80GB and I couldn't delete those files manually or with `docker system prune --valume`. After googling so many hours, I always ended with the `docker-ci-zap.exe` solution which is not recomended. Then I figured out a easy workaround by reading https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/745#issuecomment-444461889.

The workaround is adding `-removing` suffix to the folders you wish to delete within `windowsfilter` directory and restart the docker. This will trigger docker to cleanup the folders properly at startup. I have experienced docker will clean at most 10 folder in every startup. If you have more then 10 folders, then you might restart several time to remove all of them.

You can use the following command if you want to get ride of all the files.

`Get-ChildItem -Path D:\docker\data\windowsfilter -Directory | % {Rename-Item $_.FullName "$($_.FullName)-removing" -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue}`

Comment: I really wished this worked but on Docker Community Edition V18.03.0-ce-win59 (16752) this is not removing any folders.

Comment: Worked on docker for windows 4.6.0.

Comment: For me docker was deleting more than 10 files everytime I stopped the service, after a couple of restarts all files where deleted

Comment: Worked for me, first restart removed some contents but not dirs, second removed everything left.

Comment: This is just sooo beautifull, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Download `docker-ci-zap.exe` from https://github.com/jhowardmsft/docker-ci-zap and then run it in powershell with admin priviledge:

```
.\docker-ci-zap.exe -folder "C:\ProgramData\docker"
```

Reference:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26873

Comment: I used that tool, but in that same issue there is a warning that the tool might be dangerous, so i was hoping there might be another solution. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26873#issuecomment-249338936

Answer (score 3):

I use WSL 2 and this helped me: Open your PowerShell and enter the following

```sh
PS C:\tmp> diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.19041.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: *****

DISKPART> select vdisk file="C:\Users\<UID>\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx"

DiskPart successfully selected the virtual disk file.

DISKPART> compact vdisk

  100 percent completed

DiskPart successfully compacted the virtual disk file.
```

Try `wsl --shutdown` in PowerShell if it claims another process uses this disk

[Source](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699#issuecomment-693126411)

Answer (score 1):

If still relevant. I ran into the same thing.

Try the command

```
docker rmi
```

In my case problem was in that I tried execute it in linux containers mode.

When I switched into windows containers this command executing removed all content of this folder.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you. I switched to Windows Containers mode and ran: `docker system prune`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
icacls "C:\ProgramData\Docker" /T /C /grant Administrators:F
```

as administrator

Answer (score 1):

Solution update for 2021

**NOTE**:
*All command executed in ADMIN powershell*

First step: Clean all the images and the volumes.

```sh
docker image ls # These images will be all deleted
docker image prune -a -f

docker volume ls # These volumes will be all deleted
docker volume prune -a -f

docker system prune -a -f
```

Second step: Stop docker service

Right click on the docker icon or `taskkill /F /IM "Docker Desktop.exe"`. Then: `net stop com.docker.service`

Third step: Reduce the `.vhdx` file size

```sh
Optimize-VHD -Path "C:\Users\alessiosavi\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx" -Mode Full
```

Now you can restart the docker service: `net start com.docker.service`

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue trying to delete docker folder for cleanup, the below simple trick worked for me

Pre-requisite : Needs git bash to be installed

1. Rename docker folder inside c:\ProgramData\Docker\ to something like c:\ProgramData\Docker.old\
2. Run git bash inside c:\ProgramData\
3. rm -rf Docker.old\

I think the above workaround will also work with WSL terminal, but haven't tested myself